# Python : Telnet Libray, wait for promt

Tags: python, delay, wait, telnet, prompt

I'm doing automation for Cisco devices, instead of waiting for random number seconds using

`time.sleep (x)`

I want to wait for prompt `#`, so that I can proceed with `logout` command, and `tn.read_all().decode('ascii')` can read the output, I tried using,
`tn.read_until(b"#")` and  `telnet.expect([b">", b"#"])`, but both aren't helping, and always give SOCKET TIMEOUT ERROR

```
def telnet(IP,cmd,delay):
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(IP,23,5)
    tn.read_until(b"Username: ")
    tn.write(user.encode("ascii")+b"\n") #enter username
    tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
    tn.write(password.encode("ascii")+b"\n") #enter password
    #tn.read_until(b"CORE")
    tn.write(cmd.encode("ascii")+b"\n") #enter command
    tn.write(b"\n")
    print(tn.read_until(b"#"))
    tn.write(b"\n")
    tn.write(b"logout\n")
    try:
           op = tn.read_all().decode('ascii')
```

Comment: Didy you try to pass in a value for the timeout parameter in seconds? e.g. tn.read_until(b"#", timeout=60)

Comment: yes, i tired this timeout too, but no luck, maybe i should not be using tn.read_all()